# package org.apache.jena.ext.com.google.common.cache does not exist in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jena

I have downloaded Jena project with

```
git clone git://git.apache.org/jena.git
```

and compiled it with

```
mvn -U -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean install
```

It did okay.

Now I wish to open this project with `IntelliJ` but failing.

For example, in `org.apache.jena.atlas.lib.cache.CacheInfo` class it swears it can't import

```
import org.apache.jena.ext.com.google.common.cache.CacheStats;
```

How it can be possible, that maven compilation went well, while IntelliJ compilation fails?

Comment: How did you import your project on IntelliJ ?  The right way to do it is to import as an `existing maven project`. Only then it will start recognizing your packages.

Comment: It definitely recognizes SOME packages and denotes them as Maven. The problem may be is that this package belongs to some of subprojects?

Comment: This package seems to be in a jar. Try re-importing the dependencies. Open the "Maven Projects" tab/window and clicking the "Reimport All Maven Projects" in the upper left corner starts to reload all dependencies from their repositories. The status bar informs about the process.

Answer (score 2):

1. git clone git://git.apache.org/jena.git
2. open IntelliJ, and choose jena dir. (choose jena/pom.xml)
3. open jena-base/jena-base.iml. add:

   `<orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.apache.jena:jena-shaded-guava:3.11.0-SNAPSHOT" level="project"/>`
4. open jena-core/jena-core.iml. add:

   `<orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.apache.jena:jena-shaded-guava:3.11.0-SNAPSHOT" level="project">`